# How to deploy einstein bot spanish translation on production or higher sandbox environment

Tags: deployment, translation, einstein-bots, chatbot

I deployed einstein bot file higher sandbox environment. I can see einstein bot successfully deployed but spanish translation are not deployed and it is not visible in bot. Can anyone let us know how we can deploy einstein bot spanish translation on higher environment in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Translations for secondary languages can be deployed using

1. Change sets: While using this method, please make sure the Bot, Bot Version are added and then the corresponding Language is added to the change set, if you try to deploy only the language without the Bot version attached to the change set then translations for the Bots will not get deployed.

Per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_change_set.htm&type=5),

> To migrate a bot with changes in multiple languages (for example, adding a secondary language to a preexisting bot), select the Language Translation component type and include the secondary language.

2. Translation Workbench: While using this method, please make sure the new translations are added to the exported field from the target environment, this will ensure the unique keys match in the target environment while uploading the translations for the secondary language.

Per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_language_translations.htm&type=5),

> Einstein Bots supports translations entered manually or through import and export. To learn more about importing and exporting translations, visit [Export Metadata Translation Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench_export.htm&type=5) and [Import Translated Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench_import.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hi @Swetha, I have added spanish(es) translation in 86 dialogs. I retrived  spanish(es) translation from workbench. From workbench i got only 53 dialogs translations. Could you please help here why i am not getting all the einstein bot dialog translations from workbench